# Generate different gradle constants for different flavours and different build types - Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, constants

The requirement is pretty simple. But i am not finding any way to do that.
                                                                                 I have an app with **two flavours** : original and black.

```
productFlavors {
    original {

    }
    black {
        applicationIdSuffix ".black"
        versionNameSuffix "-black"
    }
}
```

Each flavour is having **two build types** : debug and release

I am generating a runtime gradle constant "APP_INFO" for different build types.

```
 buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "APPINFO", "DEBUG"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "APPINFO", "RELEASE"
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

**What i am getting right now for BuildConfig.APPINFO**

flavour : original , buildType : debug. APPINFO  "DEBUG"

flavour : original , buildType : release. APPINFO  "RELEASE"

flavour : black , buildType : debug. APPINFO "DEBUG"

flavour : black , buildType : release. APPINFO  "RELEASE"

**I need required value of APPINFO for given flavour and BuildTypes :**

flavour : original , buildType : debug.  APPINFO should be  "DEBUG_ORIGINAL"

flavour : original , buildType : release. APPINFO should be  "RELEASE_ORIGINAL"

flavour : black , buildType : debug. APPINFO should be  "DEBUG_BLACK"

flavour : black , buildType : release. APPINFO should be  "RELEASE_BLACK"

My Gradle File is as below :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
         signingConfigs {
    release {

    }
    debug {
    }
}

compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.lifeyup.app.xyz"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 7
    versionName "1.0.7"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

productFlavors {
    original {

    }
    black {
        applicationIdSuffix ".black"
        versionNameSuffix "-black"
    }
}

buildTypes {

        debug {
            original {

                buildConfigField "String", "APPINFO", "DEBUG_ORIGINAL"
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }

            black{
                buildConfigField "String", "APPINFO", "DEBUG_BLACK"
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }

    release {
        original {
            buildConfigField "String", "APPINFO", "RELEASE_ORIGINAL"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "APPINFO", "RELEASE_BLACK"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}


apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

       repositories {
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
     }

  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
   core:2.2.2', 
    {
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })
  compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
     transitive = true;
  }
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BuildConfig.DEBUG` which returns a boolean to check if build is debug or release and for checking the build flavor just check `BuildConfig.FLAVOR`

for example :
For original flavor and debug build set APPINFO as

```
if(BuildConfig.DEBUG && BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equalsIgnoreCase("original")) {
   APPINFO = "DEBUG_ORIGINAL"
} else {
   // other cases
}
```

Comment: i want the value of BuildConfig.APPINFO

Answer (score 1):

try replacing below code for build types section:

```
buildTypes {

        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            productFlavors {
                    original {
                        buildConfigField "String", "APPINFO", "DEBUG_ORIGINAL"
                    }
                    black {
                        buildConfigField "String", "APPINFO", "DEBUG_BLACK"
                    }
                }
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            productFlavors {
                    original {
                        buildConfigField "String", "APPINFO", "RELEASE_ORIGINAL"
                    }
                    black {
                        buildConfigField "String", "APPINFO", "RELEASE_BLACK"
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you can try below code also. This will work for you :

```
debug {
            productFlavors {
                original {
                    buildConfigField "String", "APPINFO", "DEBUG_ORIGINAL"
                }
                black {
                    buildConfigField "String", "APPINFO", "DEBUG_BLACK"
                }
            }
        }

release {
    //// similarly for release here
}
```

Comment: not working getting error. 
Error:(39, 0) Could not find method original() for arguments [build_kh7fbj3q82hgyf4hmjx1bqdd$_run_closure1$_closure7$_closure12$_closure14@4831e942]